# All source files for cocoa pods are compiled twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an Xcode project (objective c, Xcode 8.2.1).

Whenever I do "Clean build" and build again, it takes a very long time. I started to look into the reason for this and I noticed that all my pod source files are being compiled twice (which I guess doubles the compile time).

At the top of Xcode, you can see the status of the build as it progresses

[image]

You can see in the screenshot above that Xcode is compiling 142 source files for the Realm pod, but it only has 71 source files. All my other pods have the same issue.

I tested creating a new xcode project and adding pods, and then I don't experience the same problem as in this project.

@Bdash suggested that I might be having the build setting "Build Active Architecture Only" set to "No", but I have checked this and it is set to "Yes".

Any ideas on what could be the problem here?

Comment: Realm only has ~70 source files. Is it possible you're building your app for multiple architectures when you only need to be building for one? You can determine this by checking the "Build Active Architecture Only" configuration setting in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the comment bdash. "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to yes, so that is not the problem. I have digged a bit further, and it turns out that all my pods source files are duplicated, not just realm (I just spotted that pod initially because it was taking so long to compile). I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tends to happen when you have custom names for your build configurations. That is, if you have a name other than `Debug` or `Release`, CocoaPods will treat such configurations as release ones. Besides other things, this means enabling optimizations and setting the `Build Active Architecture Only` flag for those Pods to `YES`. Both options will hinder compilation times for `Debug` configurations.

To fix it you have to specify which configurations are `Debug` ones. Following [the docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project), you have to change your `Podfile` so it looks something like this:

```
project 'MyApp', 'MyAppRelease' => :release, 'MyAppDebug' => :debug
```

Comment: Victor, your solution fixed the issue. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Realm is a large project with a significant number of C++ and Objective-C++ source files, and generally takes a while to compile (especially after cleaning the build folder). Exactly how long Realm takes to build depends on what sort of computer Xcode is running on, but the numbers you provided don't seem to be unreasonable for older hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your comment AustinZ. I understand that Realm will take a long time too, but as bdash pointed out, all the source files are being added twice, and that doubles the already long compile time for Realm (and all other pods).